# Combining two similar queries together

Tags: mysql

I have MySQL queries both of which work fine independantly which I would like to combine together so I get three values returned.

Query 1 checks how many accounts have been deleted:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(1) AS deleted_count,
    SUBDATE(e.timestamp, INTERVAL WEEKDAY(e.timestamp) DAY) AS display_date
FROM 
    exit_reasons e
WHERE 
    e.timestamp>='$sixmonths'
GROUP BY 
    WEEKOFYEAR(e.timestamp)
ORDER BY
    display_date ASC
LIMIT 26
```

This returns a date and the number who deleted in that week

Query 2 checks how many of these have subsequently signed up again:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(1) AS date_count,
    SUBDATE(e.timestamp, INTERVAL WEEKDAY(e.timestamp) DAY) AS display_date
FROM 
    exit_reasons e
LEFT JOIN
    companies c on e.email=c.email
WHERE
    e.timestamp>='$sixmonths' AND c.email IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
    WEEKOFYEAR(e.timestamp)
ORDER BY 
    display_date ASC
LIMIT 26
```

This returns a date and the number of that weeks deleted who now have a new account

I would like it to return a date and then the number deleted and number rejoined in one query so I tried:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(1) AS date_count,
    SUBDATE(e.timestamp, INTERVAL WEEKDAY(e.timestamp) DAY) AS display_date,
    date_count as rejoined_count from
        (SELECT
            COUNT(1) AS date_count,
            SUBDATE(e.timestamp, INTERVAL WEEKDAY(e.timestamp) DAY) AS display_date
        FROM 
            exit_reasons e2
        LEFT JOIN 
            companies c on e.email=c.email
        LEFT JOIN
            companies_users cu on e.email=cu.email
        WHERE 
            e2.timestamp>='$sixmonths' AND c.email IS NOT NULL
        GROUP BY 
            WEEKOFYEAR(e.timestamp)
        ORDER BY
            display_date ASC
        LIMIT 26)
FROM 
    exit_reasons e
WHERE 
    e.timestamp>='$sixmonths'
GROUP BY 
    WEEKOFYEAR(e.timestamp)
ORDER BY
    display_date ASC
LIMIT 26
```

but I am getting a syntax error - how can I combine these queries together into one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to combine the two queries into a single query by using an aggregate function along with some conditional logic like a CASE expression:

```
SELECT
   COUNT(1) AS deleted_count,
   SUM(CASE WHEN c.email IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as date_count,
   SUBDATE(e.timestamp, INTERVAL WEEKDAY(e.timestamp) DAY) AS display_date
FROM exit_reasons e
LEFT JOIN companies c 
    on e.email=c.email
WHERE e.timestamp>='$sixmonths'
GROUP BY WEEKOFYEAR(e.timestamp)
ORDER BY display_date ASC
LIMIT 26;
```

[See Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/32c51/1).  Your check on the second query if the `c.email IS NOT NULL` is moved into the `SUM(CASE..` which allows you to get a total of the rows that are not null.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following will do what you want:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS deleted_count,
       COUNT(c.email) as date_count,
       SUBDATE(e.timestamp, INTERVAL WEEKDAY(e.timestamp) DAY) AS display_date
FROM exit_reasons e LEFT JOIN
     companies c
     on e.email = c.email
WHERE e.timestamp >= '$sixmonths'
GROUP BY  WEEKOFYEAR(e.timestamp)
ORDER BY display_date ASC
LIMIT 26;
```

In the event that someone can sign up more than once with the same email, you should change the `count()` to use `distinct`:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT e.email) as deleted_count,
COUNT(DISTINCT c.email) as date_count
```

Comment: Does this search for email not being null / now existing? Also a comma is missing after date_count but edit is too short...

Comment: @bhttoan . . . I'm not sure what "not being null / now existing" is supposed to mean.  This should have three columns in the output that correspond to your original queries.

Comment: "Is not null" is to check if the email now exists in the 2nd table - without it how can I only get those who have rejoined?

Comment: @bhttoan . . . `COUNT()` and `COUNT(DISTINCT)` only count non-NULL values.  You can think of `count(email)` as `sum(case when email is not null then 1 else 0 end)`, if you like.

Comment: OK thanks for clarifying - I still cannot get this to give me the correct output

Comment: @bhttoan . . . It should give the same output as the `sum()` with `case`.